# Sharepoint regional settings

Tags: regional-settings

I've created a Web Part using Visual Studio to show the selected columns of a list in gridview. But the problem is that whenever I'm changing the locale to English-UK (it's by default English-US), unfortunately it as well as the site has no effect on it though the date format is supposed to be changed.
I think it's all because of the custom webpart that is showing a gridview of a list.
Please help me out...
Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: So, you'd like the date formats of the appropriate fields to change when the regional settings of the site change.  Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes,this is the issue.